# Azure Data Factory Validation the Header row and checksum of a fixed length txt file and insert

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am currently using the Azure Data Factory to retrieve a fixed-length file from blob storage and trying to import the record into my database.

Fixed-length.txt

```
0202212161707
1Tom
1Kelvin
1Michael
23
```

The first row is the header record, which is start with '0' and comes up with the creation time.
The following row are the detail record, started with '1' and comes up with user name.
The last row is the end record, which started with '2' and comes up with the sum of the detail record.

However, I want to validate that the data of the file is correct before I insert those records. I would like to check if the checksum is correct first, and then only insert all those record started with 1.

Currently, I insert all those record line by line into SQL DB and run a stored procedures to perform the tasks. Is it possible to utlize Azure Data Factory to do it?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**I reproduced your issue follow below steps.**

First take one look up activity to view all the data from file and apply filter on that data.

[image]

Then take one set variable activity and get the last row's last element **e.g. 23 as 3** with below dynamic expression.

```
@last(activity('Lookup1').output.value[sub(length(activity('Lookup1').output.value),1)].Prop_0)
```

[image]

Then take one Filter activity to filter rows with 1 prefix with below items value and condition

```
items : @activity('Lookup1').output.value
condition : @startswith(item().Prop_0,'1')
```

[image]

after filter take ForEach activity to Append those values in an array

[image]

Then inside for each activity take Append variable activity it will create an array with filtered values.

[image]

Now take If condition with expression which checking value of set variable 1 and length of Append array variable is same or not.

```
@equals(int(variables('sum')),length(variables('username')))
```

[image]

Then inside true condition, add your copy activity to copy data if condition is true

**My Sample Output:**

```
0202212161707
1Tom
1Kelvin
23
```

for above data control is going to false condition.

[image]

```
0202212161707
1Tom
1Kelvin
1Michael
23
```

for above data control is going to true condition.

[image]